# What's the most efficient way to drop columns (from beginning and end) in pandas from a large dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to drop a number of columns from the beginning and end of the pandas dataframe.

My dataframe has 397 rows and 291 columns. I currently have this solution to remove the first 8 columns, but I also want to remove some at the end:

```
SMPS_Data = SMPS_Data.drop(SMPS_Data.columns[0:8], axis=1)
```

I know I could just repeat this step and remove the last few columns, but I was hoping there is a more direct way to approach this problem.

I tried using

```
SMPS_Data = SMPS_Data.drop(SMPS_Data.columns[0:8,278:291], axis=1)
```

but it doesn't work.

Also, it seems that the .drop method somehow slows down the console responsiveness, so maybe there's a cleaner way to do it?

Comment: Why not instead select the range you need to keep: `df.iloc[:, 8:278]`?

Comment: Also keep in mind you can index from the back, i.e., 8:-15

Comment: Good point. Also, this is fine as well, I think:

SMPS_Data = SMPS_Data.filter(SMPS_Data.columns[9:287], axis=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`.drop()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html), if you want to remove your columns by their column names

```
drop_these = ['column_name1', 'column_name2', 'last_columns']
df = df.drop(columns=drop_these)
```

---

If you know you want to remove them by their location, you could use [`.iloc()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df.iloc[:, 8:15]  # For columns 8-15
df.iloc[:, :-5]   # For all columns, except the last five
df.iloc[:. 2:-5]  # For all columns, except the first column, and the last five
```

See [this documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#slicing-ranges) on *indexing and slicing data* with pandas, for more information.

Comment: Perfect. The df.iloc is definitely the cleanest way and that's what I ended up using. Thank you!